# Не подсвечиваются найденные слова в разных предложениях

Tags: elasticsearch

Схема:

```
{
  "mappings": {
      "test_type": {
          "properties": {
              "sentences": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "position_increment_gap": 99,
              }
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Данные:

```
{
  "sentences": ["This is a brown fox", "This is white dog"]
}
```

Запрос:

```
{
  "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "span_near": {
                    "clauses": [
                        {
                            "span_term": { "sentences": "fox" }
                        },
                        {
                            "span_term": { "sentences": "dog" }
                        }
                    ],
                    "slop": 199,
                    "in_order": False
                }
            },
        }
    },
    "highlight" : {
        "fields" : {
            "sentences": { }
        }
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 0.009126444,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test_index",
        "_type" : "test_type",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 0.009126444,
        "_source" : {
          "sentences" : [
            "This is a brown fox",
            "This is white dog"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Подсветка в данном случае игнорируется. Как сделать так, чтобы подсветка работала, когда я ищу слова в разных предложениях? Если я ищу слова в одном предложении, то подсветка работает.

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch на данный момент не умеет подсвечивать найденый текст в элементах массива. Обсуждалось [здесь](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/7416).

Если вам непременно нужна подсветка, то лучше использовать вложенные (nested) объекты.

```
{
  "mappings": {
      "test_type": {
          "properties": {
              "sentences": {
                   "type": "nested",
                   "properties": {
                       "value": {"type": "string"}
                   }
              }
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Я нашел вариант как можно подсвечивать текст в элементах массива. Нужно в схеме указать "index_options": "offsets". И тогда все работает.

Comment: Не знал об этой опции. Спасибо, буду иметь в виду.